# Dropbox Java API : Limit access for an user

Tags: java, android, api, authentication, request

I'm working on an android app, that has to get resources from a database located on dropbox for various reasons.

I created an app limited to a folder on my dropbox's app page.

I hava data stored on this folder (i know how to do that), and want my android app to get this data. I don't want the app to be able to put files on this dropbox folder.

I know that I can generate an auth token for my app, but I need to manually "activate" it on a web browser to make it usable.

Is there a way to automatically anthenticate my android app, on any device running it, and prevent users to alterate my database, only allowing them to read data from the folder, through the dropbox's java API ?

Thanks for any answers !

Comment: any specific reason why Dropbox and not something like Firebase?

Comment: yes I've got professional reasons, can't use Firebase